# Where should my netsuite script be deployed to?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a script that changes the default for the email you can create in a record of the field Include Transaction.

What I cannot figure it out is where to deploy the script.

The url for the email pop up is https://xxxxxx-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/crm/common/crmmessage.nl?transaction=356724&entity=25778&l=T&templatetype=EMAIL

My script is:

```
function pageInit(type) {
    nlapiSetFieldValue('includetransaction', 'F');
}
```

I tried transaction and email template but it did not work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot deploy a client script to the Message record.

A workaround is to use a User Event script that "injects" the code in a custom html field that will be run client side.

```
function beforeLoad(type, form, request) {
    var script = "<script> nlapiSetFieldValue('includetransaction', 'F'); </script>";

    form
      .addField('custpage_client_script', 'inlinehtml', 'Client Script')
      .setDefaultValue(script);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a User Event script to "Message" as the Before Load function works, using the following:

```
function beforeLoad(type)
{
  nlapiSetFieldValue('includetransaction', null, null, false);
}
```